# Abuse report for an email message from amazonses.com

Tags: email, gmail, amazon-ses, yahoo-mail

I'm an AWS SES user.

I'm getting emails from `complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com`
with this message:

> This is an email abuse report for an email message from amazonses.com

Based on this [Why do I receive messages from complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com?](https://support.picnet.net/hc/en-us/articles/114094066791-Why-do-I-receive-messages-from-complaints-email-abuse-amazonses-com-)

I know that

> When you receive such an email, you should verify that the complaining recipient is not included in your future email sends.  This will ensure that you have happy email recipients and fall under the good graces of Amazon SES.

Now, my question - what can I do to reverse this action? What if customer did it by mistake, or he did not think it through.

My business is selling coupons online, sometimes with subscription.
Now what if someone make my email as a spam? I need to notify this person that his email address will never be used for future emails and I need to offer people an option to resubscribe to our service if they did it by mistake.

1) What can I recommend them todo? What is the procedure for a customer to unmark my email address as SPAM?

2) How can I deliver this message if I'm not allowed to email?

3) Does it mean that only one email address of mine was blacklisted or whole domain?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I accidentally mark an email from AWS SES as spam, I have marked it as not spam in my Yahoo mail but I still do not receive any future emails. I was using it for testing, and now I cannot have emails sent to the address that I accidentally marked as spam!

Answer (score 8):

What it says is someone whom you sent an email marked your email as spam, if you want to see who was that, you need to enable SNS notification for Complaint , SNS will tell you which recipient was it and you can remove it from the email list which you use to send emails.

> 1. What can I recommend them todo? What is the procedure for a customer to unmark my email address as SPAM?

This isn't in your control, you need to make sure your emails don't look like generic spam or marketing email. e.g: keep unsubscribe link so user can unsubscribe instead of marking it as spam.

> 2. How can I deliver this message if I'm not allowed to email?

You're still allowed to send emails but probably the email will end up in recipient junk box.

> 3. Does it mean that only one email address of mine was blacklisted or whole domain?

This is for only for one recipient mailbox but you need to control the complaint rate because if not the recipient, AWS can suspend your account if complaint rate goes high.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I had a similar issue, had 2 verified emails in AWS SES and was sending emails from one to another via SES for testing my app.

Accidentally I clicked 'spam' in one of the messages, then I reverted this by unmarking from spam, but still could not send emails to that account (my other, sender email was receiving 'complaint' notifications).

I managed to resolve this by removing the email that had 'complained' from the suppressed destinations list in AWS.

Using this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-suppression-list.html

You can view the suppression list by using:

```
aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations
```

In my case, I got back one result, the email that I had marked the sender as spam (assume it's `recipient@example.com`).

So I removed this email from that list with:

```
aws sesv2 delete-suppressed-destination --email-address recipient@example.com
```

Then I tried to send emails again from my other verified email to `recipient@example.com` and this time I can receive it.

Comment: This can also be done via the AWS web UI at https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=eu-west-1#/suppression-list (for your AWS region).

In my case I was using SES to send individual emails manually (not in bulk) and getting some "complaints" after sending to a public mailing list - instantly, so they were definitely automated and not humans clicking "Spam". I even got one "complaint" from the address of the mailing list itself - so that had to be some kind of automated spam detection thing. I solved this by disabling the AWS "Suppresion list" feature entirely.